# Create list/TEXT file of copied files after copying Batch Command

Tags: batch-file

I have created a whole batch command:

```
@echo off
set path=c:\WINDOWS\system32;
echo Copying started at %date% %time%>>_date_.txt
echo source directory ?
set /p source=
echo destination directory ?
set /p dest=
xcopy %source%\*.doc %dest%\ /s /a /d
echo Copying finished at %date% %time%>>_date_.txt
echo Completed Successfully at %date% %time%>>_date_.txt
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------- >>_date_.txt
pause
```

Now I am wondering, is it also possible to create a batch command that will automatically create a TXT file of the files that have been copied after copying all the files with the XCOPY command.

Answer (score 3):

By default `XCOPY` displays the filenames of the copied files.

So, to get the list of copied files, just redirect xcopy output to a file

this way

```
XCOPY %source%\*.doc %dest%\ /s /a /d >copied.lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you !! This worked fine for me !!

What I have done now is the following:

```
@echo off

set path=c:\WINDOWS\system32;

echo Copying started at %date% %time%>>_date_.txt

echo source directory ?
set /p source=
echo destination directory ?
set /p dest=
xcopy %source%\*.doc %dest%\ /s /a /d >copied.txt

echo Copying finished at %date% %time%>>_date_.txt

echo Completed Successfully at %date% %time%>>_date_.txt

echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------- >>_date_.txt

pause
```

Comment: to comment an answer, use the "add comment" function below the answer, don't post another answer. And, if the answer worked for you, please accept it.

Comment: And please use just one account.